# Como setar $GOPATH em pasta existente?

Tags: golang

Eu quero **instalar** um *pacote* em um *projeto* em `go`

```
go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
```

Porém ao **digitar** esse **comando** no `terminal` do **Ubuntu**

```
package github.com/gorilla/mux: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Gostaria de saber *como faço* para **setar** `$GOPATH` nessa **pasta já existente** em qual estou *escrevendo* o projeto.

Comment: Digita no terminal `go env` e posta o resultado...

Answer (score 1):

$GO_PATH é a *enviroment variable* que define onde ficarão todas as suas coisas relacionadas a Go, incluindo

- Todas as bilbiotecas que você baixar.
- Todo o código fonte dos projetos.
- Todos os arquivos binários resultadas pela compilação do código fonte dos seus projetos.

Repara que isso é diferente da maioria dos linguages, que tem uma pasta para cada projeto e guardam os arquivos/bibliotecas/binários na pasta dos seus respectivos projetos.

Veja o exemplo de organização de arquivos retirado da [documentação oficial](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization):

```
bin/
    hello                          # command executable
    outyet                         # command executable
pkg/
    linux_amd64/
        github.com/golang/example/
            stringutil.a           # package object
src/
    github.com/golang/example/
        .git/                      # Git repository metadata
    hello/
        hello.go               # command source
    outyet/
        main.go                # command source
        main_test.go           # test source
    stringutil/
        reverse.go             # package source
        reverse_test.go        # test source
    golang.org/x/image/
        .git/                  # Git repository metadata
    bmp/
        reader.go              # package source
        writer.go              # package source
    #... (many more repositories and packages omitted) ...
```

Agora, se mesmo assim você achar melhor setar o $GO_PATH para pasta do seu projeto:

1 - Navegue até a pasta desejada

2 - Digite o comando:

```
$ echo $PWD >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Lembre-se que você vai ter que fazer isso toda vez que mudar de projeto, já que os comandos em Go irão procurar tudo na página que você setou o $GO_PATH

Comment: bash_profile é o nome do meu usuário?

Comment: Não. É um arquivo que fica dentro da sua pasta /home/<nome do usuário> (O atalho para essa pasta é "~/". Tente escrever "cd ~/" no terminal.). .bash_profile é um arquivo especial que é executado sempre que o seu usuário loga em um terminal.